# Saving Fonts in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtextpane, java-font

As a part of learning Java GUI Programming with `javax.swing` I intend to save contents of a `JTextPane` with `Font` information. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can save the contents of JTextPane using HTMLEditorKit or RTFEditorKit.

```
StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument)textPane.getDocument();

HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();

BufferedOutputStream out;

try {
    out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("rich.html")));

    kit.write(out, doc, doc.getStartPosition().getOffset(), doc.getLength());

} catch (FileNotFoundException | IOException e) {
} catch (BadLocationException e) {
}
```

Comment: I would have said to look at the `StyledDocument` if your answer had not beaten me to it by [checks watch] 17 months. Nice one!